# Spring - Inject proper service implementation in abstract class level autowired field

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have 2 class hierarchies:

```
* ClassA
  * ClassB

* AbstractClass
  * Class1
  * ...
  * Class5
```

`AbstractClass` autowires `ClassA`  as follows:

```java
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Autowired
    protected ClassA classA;
}
```

Now I would like to inject `ClassA` into `Class1`, .., `Class4` implementations but `ClassB` into `Class5`. I'm aware that I can do that by injecting directly in implementing classes rather than in abstract class (as in [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507041/inject-in-abstract-class-based-on-subclass)) but that means that I have to have the same field declared not once but five times. Additionally if I want to use this field in abstract class I would have to enforce creating getter in implementing class and use it to get that service. It works but it doesn't seem to me like right way to do it.

Comment: You can use constructor injection in the child classes

Comment: Could you show example as an answer? So if it works I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
@Component
class ClassA {}

@Component
class ClassB extends ClassA {}

abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected ClassA classA;
}

@Component
class Class1 extends AbstractClass {
    public Class1(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }
}
//... Same for Class2/3/4

@Component
class Class5 extends AbstractClass {
    public Class5(ClassB classB) {
        this.classA = classB;
    }
}
```

This lets you have the common property and methods in the abstract class and if qualify them in the child classes using constructor injection

Comment: Definitely looks better and allows for direct access to service in the upper class. Thanks for help!